# How to install AppScale on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)?

Tags: google-app-engine, appscale

When trying to install AppScale

```
root@node2391-ubuntu:~# wget -O bootstrap.sh http://bootstrap.appscale.com && bash ./bootstrap.sh


HEAD is now at a3087c2... Merge pull request #2410 from whoarethebritons/3.2.1
Note: checking out '3.2.1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 6815257... Merge pull request #612 from whoarethebritons/3.2.1
Building AppScale...Updating package list and cache ...done.
Ubuntu/xenial is not supported.
failed!
root@node2391-ubuntu:~#
```

What is the work-arount to install Appscale on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in the process of merging the pull request to build appscale in xenial. You can try to build it by hand using https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/pull/2437 or you can wait few days, while the branch is been reviewed and then merged.

Comment: Thanks we can wait for it, in the meantime we tried Appscale with Docker and we are having issues running it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003823/running-appscale-on-jelastic

Comment: ok PR should be merged soon. I follow up on the other thread.

Comment: is this the reason why when we try to do it on Docker we are not able to run it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appscale_community/wUrPbxjFfWI